# Opencv 2.4.3 estimateRigidTransform in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

This is really a mess for me and I have a hard time trying to solve this. I want to use the method cv2.estimateRigitTransform in Python with numpy arrays but I can't find anywhere an example or something else that explains the format of the src and dst numpy arrays needed.

Could somebody send me a little example of these 2 arrays that will work with this method? I have all the data (in 2D of course) but can't find how to shape it in a numpy array.

Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [reading the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=estimate#cv2.estimateRigidTransform)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a basic example that tries to align two random sets of 10 points

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
shape = (1, 10, 2) # Needs to be a 3D array
source = np.random.randint(0, 100, shape).astype(np.int)
target = source + np.array([1, 0]).astype(np.int)
transformation = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(source, target, False)
```

[Documentation is here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, your source array will be something like [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... , [x10, y10]]. Is that correct?

Comment: I noticed a problem. It needs to have a 3rd dimension, or it will treat your matrices as images, and try to do I-don't-know-what, maybe some sort of image alignment.

Comment: Hey @Jeep87c, this is similar to your other question. What are you hoping to achieve? It's pretty easy to make your own least-squares point-set alignment. Maybe you could describe exactly what you want?

Comment: I have been trying to get estimateRigidTransform working for a couple of days... I wanted to add that the 3D part is important, but also the astype() is important for cv2 to recognize the vector properly. It doesn't have to be of type np.int, but the array definitely needs a dtype defined for cv2 to work properly. Hopefully this saves someone a headache someday.

Comment: To add to Brian's comment, it needs to be np.float32, the function does not accept np.float64 and the error message: "Both input images must have either 8uC1 or 8uC3 type in function cvEstimateRigidTransform" only applies to the 2D image situation. You have to dive into the source code to see this line: "else if( CV_MAT_TYPE(A->type) == CV_32FC2 || CV_MAT_TYPE(A->type) == CV_32SC2 )"